# Python - Capture single quotes but not apostrophes using regex

Tags: python, regex, parsing

Sometimes the docs that I'm searching through have an uneven number of quotation marks. I can easily find all these occurrences if they contain double quotation marks, but the single quotation marks are throwing me off. How would I capture just the single quotation marks without also capturing apostrophes like in `you're`, `Rob's`, `Womens'`, `didn't` etc.

**EDIT**

For instance, this

```
"my friend likes apples.
```

will get captured by this

```
rgxDoubleQuotes = re.compile('\"')
for charseq in root.findall(".//span[@type='sentence']/extent/charseq[@START]"): 
if rgxDoubleQuotes.findall(charseq.text):
    if charseq.text.count("\"") % 2 != 0:
        print charseq.text
```

But it will not capture

```
'your dog just pissed.
```

I want to be able to capture the second without also capturing sentences containing apostrophes like in

```
the cat's name is same
```

Comment: By "capture just the single quotation marks" do you mean capturing the text *between* the quotes?

Comment: If I remember my long ago academic classes correctly, this is not actually possible with non-recursive regular expressions. You'd need to keep track of nesting level, and regexps don't do that. It's essentially the same problem as finding mismatched parens. Some languages have recursion extensions to their regular expression libraries, but Python does not.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper:  I think quotes may be exempt from this problem because they don't nest.

Comment: I guess it's a question of how you can tell the difference - in a line like `'foo bar' baz'`, which quote is mismatched? Parity checking the number of `'` characters would be easy, distinguishing `you're` from `foo'bar` not so much. So the nesting problem doesn't actually apply, but the distinction seems underdefined.

Comment: It's probably too optimistic, but are the only times you want to capture single quotes when they appear as the first character?

Comment: The answer is probably going to involve matching word boundaries with \b

Comment: @jedwards, most of the time. But often it will occur in the middle somewhere. I need to capture those too.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper: the new regex module has the recursion feature: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex

Comment: I think an apostrophe is always within a word (no spaces either side) or in the following form: "s' ". That's for standard English; slang often has others ("good ol' times") and probably cannot be accounted for.

Comment: @mdurant, I guess I could narrow down my search by looking for those that don't have letters on both sides. Thanks.

Comment: Good luck. I think you cannot fully rely on an automated program for your messed up content. Example: Line1: 'I went to Vas' party last night Line2: 'I went to Mars' said Mark.